# Login to salesforce.com with Phantomjs 2.0 keep asking for verification code

Tags: authentication, phantomjs, salesforce, verification

We are doing some tests to connect to the  salesforce.com  with Phantomjs 2.0.
It was working pretty good, but in the last couple of weeks salesforce.com  kept asking for the verification code every new session.

Is anyone experiencing the same issue?

Comment: Have you checked that they allow such a thing? Also, *"Is anyone experience same issue?"* is not a particularly useful question. What's your actual *programming* question?

Comment: We having problem running selenium scripts with Salesforce.com using Phantomjs 2.0. Every time we are running a script on the local, we are getting verification screen.

Answer (score 2):

You can whitelist your IP address in order to stop Salesforce for asking the verification code.
Go to **Setup -> Security -> Network Access** and add your IP to whitelist.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not an option for us, due to security policy.

Answer (score 2):

This should perhaps be a comment, but as I do not have the required points to comment please forgive the "answer". This is a working answer, as I'm not very proficient in casper/phantom I will update on attempted solutions. Hopefully my attempts will help someone else.

> Is anyone experiencing the same issue?

A: *Yes*

**Problem:** As of [Salesforce Spring '16 update](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000232553) when logging into SF from a new browser SF authenticates the user with a verification code (can be tested with a new browser eg.firefox). Oddly the issue doesn't replicate with an incognito session.

**Proposed solution:** Create a cookies file & login to SF with the casper/phantom scripts. Saving the authentication to the JS cookies file, otherwise every login will require a verification.

**Testing steps:**

1. We can see the verification form using casper/phantom.

   ```
   var fs = require('fs'); //top of script
   var html = this.getHTML(); //place this in wait_function() after login()  
   fs.write('./output.html', html, 'w');
   ```
2. We can now "fill" the verification form with the emailed code

   ```
   this.click('phSearchInput', function () { //'phSearchInput' found in above extract
   this.fill('form', {
   'phSearchInput' : '*verification_number_here*'
    }, true);
   ```

   2.1 There seems to be an issue with the final redirect after the verification. I'm not sure how much time I can give this (as it's not a priority) and I'm quite new to JS. I'll leave the code here for reference/testing

   ```
   /*Altered from http://blog.deadlypenguin.com/blog/2013/07/09/logging-into-salesforce-with-casperjs/ */

   var LOGIN_URL, LOGIN_USERNAME, LOGIN_PASSWORD, casp;

   casp = require('casper').create({
        viewportSize: {
             width: 1024,
             height: 768
        },
        verbose: true,
        logLevel: 'debug'
   });

   casp.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4');

   if (!casp.cli.has('username') && !casp.cli.has('password')) {
        casp.echo('Usage: $ casperjs sfdclogin.casper.js --username=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD [--prod]').exit(-1);
   }

   if (casp.cli.has('prod')) {
        LOGIN_URL = 'https://test.salesforce.com//';
   } else {
        LOGIN_URL = 'https://test.salesforce.com/';
   }

   LOGIN_USERNAME = casp.cli.get('username');
   LOGIN_PASSWORD = casp.cli.get('password');

   casp.start(LOGIN_URL, function () {

        this.log('Logging in', 'debug');
       //login
        this.fill('form', {
             'username': LOGIN_USERNAME,
             'pw': LOGIN_PASSWORD
        }, true);

        this.log('Logged in', 'debug');
    });

   casp.wait(5000, function () {

        this.log('Varification START', 'debug');
        this.fill('form', {
             'emc': '*verification_number_here*'
        }, true);

        this.captureSelector('test.png', 'html');
        this.log('Varification FINISHED', 'debug');
        this.wait(6000)

   }, 12000);

   casp.then(function () {
   //casp.waitForUrl('https://cs31.salesforce.com/home/home.jsp', function() {

        this.log('Are we logged in??');
        this.captureSelector('test2.png', 'html');

   }, 12000);

   casp.run();
   ```
3. Add a cookies file in hopes the verification validation is saved there. (I'll get to this when I figure out step 3).